Prediction intervals for simple linear regression
I want to understand how to construct the test statistic for the case of predictive inference for a simple linear regression model and would be grateful if someone might confirm if my derivation is correct please. We have fit a model on the training data and have our fitted values
$$
\widehat{Y}_i = \widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta}x_i
$$
If we want to construct a prediction interval for a new observation $x_0$ we have that
$$
\widehat{Y}_0 = \widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta}x_0
$$
and that
$$
\widehat{Y}_0 \sim N \big( \alpha + \beta x_0, k \sigma^2\big)
$$
where $k$ is a constant. Since we know the distribution of the sample variance $S^2$
$$
S^2 \sim \frac{\sigma^2}{n-p} \chi^2 (n-p)
$$
Then if define $P = \widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta}x_0 - Y_0$ then we can construct a standard normal random variable $P / k \sigma^2$
$$
P \sim N \Big(0, \sigma^2 k \Big) \Rightarrow \frac{P}{\sigma \sqrt{k}} \sim N \big(0, 1 \big)
$$
By definition of the t-distribution, a random variable $T = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{U/u}}$ follows the t-distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom
$$
\text{ where } Z = \frac{P}{\sigma \sqrt{k}} \sim N \big(0,1\big), \ \ \  \frac{U}{u} = \frac{S^2 (n-2)}{\sigma^2 (n-2)}, U \sim \chi^2 (n-2)
$$
such that
$$
T = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{U}/\sqrt{u}} = \frac{P}{\sigma \sqrt{k}} \times \frac{\sqrt{n-2}\sigma}{S \sqrt{n-2}} = \frac{P}{\sqrt{k}S} = \frac{\widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta}x_0 - Y_0}{kS}
$$
Then given a selected size for the test, $p$, we can construct a prediction interval with the quantile $t_f$ where $f = p/2$
$$
\bigg(\widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta}x_0 - t_f s\sqrt{k}, \widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta}x_0 + t_f s\sqrt{k} \bigg)
$$
If someone wouldn't mind confirming the working / thinking here that would be amazing. Thanks in advance.
